# FFmpeg batch merge videos within a folder

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file, merge

I have a folder `c:\myfolder\` containing a **variable** amount of `mp4` files with same resolution / codec.

Now I need a .bat file to merge all videos into one.

e.g. `c:\myfolder\1.mp4, c:\myfolder\2.mp4, c:\myfolder\3.mp4` into `c:\myfolder\output.mp4`

I've found a way to do this by creating a `.txt` file first which contains all input videos and to do in another step

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

Question: Is there a way to do this in one step?

Comment: A batch file could produce the `.cue` file for you, but I see a sorting problem if there are more than 9 files as 10.mp4 will follow 1.mp4 unless you use a counting `for /l` to build the list.

Comment: @LotPings there is no sorting problem since the files have sortable timestamps - could you write your code into a answer?

Answer (score 5):

For those who use `bash` (Linux/Mac), here is the script to generate the list of all files in a folder and then merge it all into one video file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in pieces/*.mp4; do
  echo "file $filename" >> concat-list.txt
done

ffmpeg -f concat -i concat-list.txt merged.mp4

echo "Concatenated videos list:"
cat concat-list.txt
rm concat-list.txt
```

It takes all `mp4` files from `pieces/` folder and concatenates the videos into `merged.mp4` file.

Files list is generated in alphabetical order, so if you want the videos to be in a particular order, name them like `01-murder-scene.mp4`, `02-office-scene.mp4` etc.

Comment: See also https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: if the files are absolute (i changed files path) then need to add `-safe 0` to the ffmpeg command.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have ffmpeg installed on this pc, untested:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\20\SU_1332169.cmd
@Echo off
Set "BaseDir=c:\myfolder"
Set "OutMp4=%BaseDir%\Output.mp4"
Set "FfmpegCue=%Temp%\Ffmpeg.Cue"

:: gather files but exclude evt. present output file
( For /f "Delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S/A-D/ON "%BaseDir%\*.mp4" 2^>NUL ^|findstr /VLI "%OutMp4%" '
  ) Do Echo=%%A
) > "%FfmpegCue%"

:: Just to show what's in the cue file:
more "%FfmpegCue%"
Pause

:: Do the concat
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i "%FfmpegCue%" -c copy "%OutMp4%" && (
  Echo Successfully created "%OutMp4%"
  choice /M "Delete %FfmegCue% "
  If not Errorlevel 2 Del "%FfmegCue%"
) || (echo ffmpeg exited with error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick Python script for Windows to combine mp4 files. It sorts the files based on creation time (oldest to newest) but you can modify the script to change the sorting procedure.

In my case, I'm using [OBS](https://obsproject.com/download) where I'm creating multiple short clips, one after the other. The script does a good job at combining them all together into one mp4 file. For quick and dirty jobs that don't require any editing, using this script is much faster than using an editing program like [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/).

The prerequisites for running this script are installing [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) and [Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). ffmpeg must be added to your [Windows path](https://windowsloop.com/install-ffmpeg-windows-10/) if it isn't automatically added upon installation.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import glob

# Create list of all .mp4 files in current working directory.
files = list(filter(os.path.isfile, glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '*.mp4'))))
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(x))

# Write list to text file that ffmpeg reads next.
with open('files.txt', 'w') as output:
    for file in files:
        output.write("file '" + file + "'\n")

# Run ffmpeg to concatenate the .mp4 files.
os.system('ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt merged.mp4')

# Delete the text file.
os.remove('files.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, since it creates temporary file. But I would like to provide people with a straightforward answer as an alternative:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Synopsis: Combine any input videos to a mp4 file.
# Usage: ffmpeg-combine-videos input_video1 input input_video2 ...

n=0

rm -f __input*
> __input.list

for i in "$@";do
    I=__input${n}.ts
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v h264 -b:v ${VIDEO_BITRATE:-400k} -c:a libmp3lame -f mpegts "$I"
    echo "file $I" >> __input.list
    n=$((n+1))
done

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i __input.list -c copy combined.mp4

rm -f __input*
```