# Youtube playlist to m4b audiobook

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

Currently I download youtube playlists as audio `-f 140`, transfer the files via itunes to my iphone, then add a common artist/ablum metadata in itunes move it from music to audiobooks.

However, this process doesn't leave the chapters in the right (original) order.

The best solution I can come up with is prefix the file names with the playlist index so that the alphabetic ordering is the same as the playlist's. Then concat as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1332169/ffmpeg-batch-merge-videos-within-a-folder). Will post code next time I need to do this, but maybe someone can figure out a nicer method.

Answer (score 0):

This process was more involved than I imagined. You have to handcraft the chapter metadata, ffmpeg doesn't do it for you. After all that, the actual concat muxing is disk IO bound, and only 68x speed up ended up frustratingly slow for my use. You can speed it up using [TMPFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71675183/how-to-speed-up-ffmpegs-copy). To do this properly you would read the entire chapter into memory, and write the output into memory.

Original source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/745238/how-to-merge-multiple-mp4-files-as-chapters-in-a-final-mp4

My changes to wget
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tom-huntington/1323af4b991ca34ef4a46b3e44532ada/raw/a21b7e2ba48fc68fdda7c15b3f9cf28594cbffe1/script.py